# Resize Bluestack Screen on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, android, terminal-emulator, bluestacks

I need to check the application compatibility in all device & debuging application on Bluestack App Player, can anyone please tell me how to resize the screen of Bluestack on Mac OS X? I googled it and found that in Windows the screen size can be changed via register as shown below :

```
Go to regedit: 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\BlueStacks\Guests\Android\FrameBuffer\0 
"Width"=dword:00000320 - change value 
"Height"=dword:00000258 - change value
```

But I'm new to Mac OS X where do I find the regedit?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you can't just drag the window edge or corner to resize it, try this:

First, quit the program (**Bluestacks** > **Quit** in the menu bar or press <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd>).

If Bluestacks App Player is like a typical OS X application, you can find the preferences file (Mac OS X does not have a central configuration facility like the Windows Registry) in `~/Library/Preferences/`. There you should look for a file like `com.bluestacks.appplayer.plist` or something similar.

You can open the plist file in a text editor or Xcode. Then look for a key corresponding to window size (it will probably start with `NS`) and then adjust the size as needed.

Based on the comment below, the property is found at `guests > android > height`.

Note that for more recent versions of OS X (since at least 10.9) you need to use the `defaults` utility in terminal to make the change.

Comment: thanks a lot but there is small change in ur answer that is in com.bluestacks.appplayer.plist in guests->android->height and width can be adjusted

Comment: @Stacks28 Gotcha. So this would be a custom property then. System properties stored in plist files often start with `NS`.

Comment: i hv one more issue ..how ca i restart bluestack when i change the size, i tired closing bluestack process from Aactive monitor but didnt helped

Comment: @Stacks28 Oh, sorry. You should quit Bluestacks first (open the Bluestacks menu and choose Quit at the bottom or press ⌘Q) before applying the changes to the preference file.

Comment: When i changed the size and re-open the app player it did resize the window but "android" didn't resize. I'd fixed that by setting the "RestartGuestOnFrontendLaunch" to 1. Can be found under guests > android > config. What it does is restarting "android" when closed out the app player/opening bluestack. You can change it back when everything is resized.

Comment: I think this doesn't work anymore...

Comment: @Kache Could you be more specific?

Comment: I believe I've followed the outlined procedure, correctly, but I'm not seeing any changes.

Comment: @Kache If you are editing the file directly in 10.9, it may not work anymore due to preferences caching. Instead you should do `defaults write DOMAIN KEY VALUE`.

Comment: Using that command isn't working in 10.12.6, maybe I'm not using it correctly? https://superuser.com/questions/1297568/how-to-use-the-defaults-command-to-resize-bluestacks

Answer (score 3):

In ~/Library/Preferences, you'll find a file named com.BlueStacks.AppPlayer.plist.  If you open this file with Xcode, you'll find the screen size settings by drilling down into:  Guests->Android->FrameBuffer.  You'll find the width & height settings under the FrameBuffer dictionary.

Note:  Install your Android applications before you change the screen size.  You may find the (web) view BlueStacks uses to access the Google Play store doesn't use your updated screen size.

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for the Google Play store not being resized?

Comment: No.  I haven't had a need to look for one.

Answer (score 2):

As of BlueStacks 2.0.1.14, the following solutions **don't work** anymore (editing `~/Library/Preferences/com.BlueStacks.AppPlayer.plist`):

1. Adding/Modifying Root > Guests > Android > Config > RestartGuestOnFrontendLaunch and set to 1.
2. Adding/Modifying Root > Guests > Android > Height and set to desired value.

The only working solution is to change:

Root > Guests > Android > FrameBuffer >

- Height: 540
- Width: 960
- WindowHeight: 540
- WindowWidth: 960

I edit it with Xcode, save and re-launch BlueStack. Works perfectly on Mojave 10.14.1.

(I set to 960 x 540, half size of original)

Comment: Works again in v4.11

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded a software called [ResizeEnable](http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/Resize) (freeware) that can resize all windows, now it's working fine.

Comment: Link is incorrect: it should be: http://www.digitallis.co.uk/pc/ResizeEnable/ That app is also for Windows, and this question relates to Mac