# How to use the defaults command to resize bluestacks?

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, bluestacks

I'm trying to resize the bluestacks window using the command below. I'm trying to change it to 1200x800.

```
defaults write com.bluestacks.BlueStacks "NSWindow Frame browserWindow" "-48 -22 1200 800 0 0 1200 800 "
```

Seems that the command works:

```
defaults read com.bluestacks.BlueStacks
{
    "NSWindow Frame browserWindow" = "-48 -22 1200 800 0 0 1200 800 ";
}
```

But when I open bluestacks it doesn't have the new size and the settings have been overwritten.

```
defaults read com.bluestacks.BlueStacks
{
    "NSWindow Frame browserWindow" = "-48 -22 1536 899 0 0 1440 877 ";
}
```

macOS Sierra 10.12.6

Comment: Use `man defaults` to see syntax examples. You appear to be missing the type declaration at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

The way I was finally able to resize the window was by editing the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.BlueStacks.AppPlayer.plist`.

I changed these values:

```
                            <key>WindowHeight</key>
                            <integer>600</integer>
                            <key>WindowWidth</key>
                            <integer>1200</integer>
```